# When creating a git repository that will be on the server, can I convert it to a bare repository?

Tags: git, git-bare, git-non-bare-repository

I already created a repository. Can I make it a bare type or shall I start over?

Answer (score 41):

According to the [FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#How_do_I_make_existing_non-bare_repository_bare.3F), conversion from non-bare to bare can be done in two ways. The best one:

```
$ git clone --bare -l repo repo.git
$ rm -rf repo
```

To create a bare repository from scratch:

```
$ mkdir repo.git
$ cd repo.git
$ git --bare init
```

Comment: Why is the first method "easier"? The second method seems both safer *and* easier (you don't need the renames to get the same result as the first method, just `git clone --bare repo` followed by `rm -rf repo` will do).

Comment: @Dan is right, and I have modified my answer to only contain the safe *and* easy approach. With the version of git on my box (1.5.6.5), I still need to provide the target directory when calling git-clone, though.

Comment: Doesn't `git clone` set the `origin` remote to the one cloned from? In this case to `./repo`, which you `rm`'d...

Comment: The [FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#HowdoImakeexistingnon-barerepositorybare.3F) now suggests `git clone --bare -l`.  The `-l` asks for hardlinks, which makes this faster.  Although note that by using git clone you lose config settings/remotes, so beware.

Comment: @Marius: Thanks for the heads-up. I have an `-l` and updated the FAQ link to reflect URL changes.

Comment: Note that hardlinking with -l will save time and space during cloning *and* prevent you from loosing data if you later remove the non-bare repo, as the files are still linked by the bare one. Of course it only works if your file system supports hard links..

Answer (score 20):

Just move the `.git` folder away from the working copy.

```
mv /var/git/repo/repo/.git /var/git/repos/repo.git
```

You might want to follow that up with a

```
git config --bool core.bare true
```

in that repository, just in case `git` complains about something not being right.

Comment: how do I create a bare repo rigth from the start?

Comment: Pass the `--bare` flag to `git`: `$ mkdir myrepo.git && cd myrepo.git && git --bare init`

Comment: Or just `git init --bare myrepo.git`

Comment: Note that being able to do `git init --bare` as an alternative to `git --bare init` came in in v1.5.6 ~Jun 08.

Answer (score 5):

```
git clone --bare repo
```

This will give you a new bare version of `repo` named `repo.git`. Easy, no?