# How do i make a non-bare git repository into a bare one?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a git repository from normal to bare ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-git-repository-from-normal-to-bare)

I would like to make a repo into a bare repo so people can push to it with out big nasty warnings. I could delete it and clone it again... but perhaps there is a more elegant way?

Comment: should I call these bare repositories or sparse repositories?

Comment: git calls them 'bare' repositories, as in `git clone --bare`.

Comment: thanks :) edit: s/sparse/bare/g

Comment: This was cloned from a svn repo so cloning agail will take loooong time.

Comment: see my comment in my answer: just clone the git repo, not the original svn repo.

Answer (score 13):

It's probably best to just delete and clone again. Example:

```
mv old_git_repo/ /tmp/
git clone --bare /tmp/old_git_repo/  new_git_repo/
```

You could also just remove the working files and promote `.git/*` to `.`. However, you'd also need to add `bare = true` and remove `logallrefupdates = true` in the new bare `config`'s `[core]` section (formerly `.git/config`. You could make a script to do this automatically if you like.

**Edit:** You mentioned in a comment that this was cloned from svn, so a new clone will take a long time. But - don't clone from svn! Just clone from the new git repo, and it will be `git -> git`, which will be fast. Or, see my note above about just moving the files.

Comment: I second the recommendation to clone (git->git, not svn->git, of course). It's always best to avoid mucking around inside `.git` if you can, even though this is a pretty simple manipulation.

Comment: I get a "Too many arguments" error when I run `git clone --bare /path/to/existing_repo /path/to/new_repo`. I've also tried it with a trailing `/.git` on the first argument.

Comment: Manipulating the `.git` directory didn't work for me, only this worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A bare repository is simply a .git directory without the working directory. So you can simply replace the project dir with the contents of .git and it should work:

```
mv /path/to/projectdir /path/to/projectdir.old
mv /path/to/projectdir.old/.git /path/to/projectdir
rm -rf /path/to/projectdir
```

Comment: You should also set the `core.bare` configuration option to a true value. But, it is probably best to just use `git clone --bare`.

Comment: You're right, a "git config core.bare 1" command is also needed. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Shouldn't the third line be `rm -rf /path/to/projectdir.old`? You're keeping the working directory and throwing away the git database.