# pause git clone and resume later?

Tags: git, git-clone

Is there a way to pause git clone and resume it later? I'm cloning a really big repo (around 2GB) and my PC's been turned on for more than 40 hours. I have school to catch later, I don't want to leave it like this. Anybody got an idea? It's already at 67% btw. :(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming it's a normal `git clone`, I'm afraid that they're not resumable, as far as I know.  To add support for resumable `git clone` / `git fetch` has been a suggested project for the Google Summer of Code in the past.

One exception is if you're actually doing a `git svn clone`, then you can restart it by changing into the directory and running `git svn fetch`, but I assume that this is just a normal git repository you're cloning.  For some other ideas of how to work around this, you might want to try the suggestions in the answers to this question:

- [How to complete a git clone for a big project on an unstable connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3954852/223092)

Comment: ha! Thank you! I did look around google but didn't find any clear cut answers. I'm afraid it's a normal git clone. But thanks for informing me about git svn... :D

Comment: btw.. The git clone just finished minutes after your post. Oh my, am I lucky. Anyhow, thanks sir, I'll try to remember that.

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear that worked out.

Comment: September 2014: any news?

Comment: You saved me for the `git svn` part thank you a lot !

Answer (score 26):

Depending on your situation (e.g. if you want to close your laptop and / or switch networks), stopping the process (using `Ctrl-Z`) and resuming it (using `fg`) might work for you.

Comment: Or, if the computer is about to shutdown (and you are running Linux), you can use something like [CryoPID](http://cryopid.berlios.de/)

Comment: This worked for me, and i have been doing that... stop the process, put the PC into hibernation and resume the process.

Comment: After "fg" git told me the pipe was broken. So it did not work for me. But the idea itself is nice one.