# invalid index-pack output on git

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, git-bash, atlassian-sourcetree

So I have a large Unity project (Approx 12 gigs on GitLab). I have cloned this repo multiple times before, with absolutely no problems. But since 2 days, after a few merges, I've been trying to update my branch and have been running git pull and also tried a fresh clone. Everytime i try, It fails at the exact same % with the following error. I cant seem to find ANYTHING online related to this, especially the "Waiting for packfile negotiation: context canceled" error.

I am guessing it might be my network connection (though not choppy at all, its about 2MB/s) because when i ran

`git fetch --depth=1`,  i had no problems.

Below is the Error and i would appreciate any help:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 73987, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (73986/73986), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (17723/17723), done.
remote: g objects:  33% (23640/70335), 1.07 GiB | 1.10 MiB/s
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
remote: ERROR: waiting for packfile negotiation: context canceled

remote:
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

I tried a fresh clone, i tried cloning with depth =1 and that seemed to work, but this is really important since i cannot absolutely continue my work

Comment: The error "waiting for packfile negotiation: context canceled" is from Gitlab: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitaly/-/issues/4441

Comment: On the other hand the error "fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet" is quite a well-known: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fetch-pack%3A+unexpected+disconnect+while+reading+sideband+packet . The solution is `git config http.postBuffer 524288000`; if doesn't help [clone in small steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16736600/7976758). If still doesn't help try to switch to `ssh://` protocol.

Comment: It's a timeout. Git builds "packfiles" by compressing commits with gzip, but if the pack building process takes too long (common if you have lots of large files in Git proper) then the session may time out before it finishes.

Comment: Is it because of gzip problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the Problem was with my internet connection. I bumped the speed up by about 1Mb/s and it pulled fine with no problems

Comment: If in LAN, net speed alredy proximity to 100 mib/s, still have this issue