# SVN checkout on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: github, svn, connection, svn-checkout

I have a code base hosted on GitHub and need to check out this code base to Raspberry Pi with minimal external interaction so that once the checkout is initiated and internet connection fails in between, system should be able to continue checkout once internet is available, without any manual interactions. Please suggest.

Comment: If the code is hosted on Github, then it's probably a git repo and you need to use "git clone" to bring a copy down locally, not the svn command?

Comment: Basically, I am looking for a solution for to complete synchronisation on an unstable internet connection without much interaction. My understanding is that whatever command is used, while the command is running and internet fails in between, I have to re-run the commands. I am looking for a set up in which some cron jobs will run periodically in my Raspberry Pi and if my Pi is connected to internet during specific time period, my local repository will get updated and any internet connection issues should be taken care by svn commands or in some other ways.

Answer (score -1):

These posts might help with doing a 'git clone' on an unstable connection.  Once you have the clone operation done, fetching updates will hopefully be less traffic.

- 2013: [How to complete a git clone for a big project on an unstable connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954852/how-to-complete-a-git-clone-for-a-big-project-on-an-unstable-connection)
- 2012: [pause git clone and resume later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805274/pause-git-clone-and-resume-later)
- 2013: [Does git-clone have resume capability?](https://superuser.com/questions/512190/does-git-clone-have-resume-capability)

Some of the suggestions boil down to:

- Do a git clone on a machine with a stable connection
- rsync or transfer it to the Raspberry Pi using a resumable transfer method
- hope that future fetch/pull get through

However, there's still no way to resume a pull/clone if it fails mid-stream with git.  As long as your internet connection is stable long enough for the 'git fetch' to run to completion, you would be okay.