# git: retry if http request failed

Tags: git, http

In our Continuous Integration environment we do very heavy usage of `git clone` and `git update`.

Sometimes the network or the central git server is not reliable.

Is there a way to tell git to retry if the http request failed?

Example:

> 500 Internal Server Error while accessing 
>   https://example.com/repos/foo_bar/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack

Comment: The Git command should return a proper [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) which you can check for success of the command. If it didn’t succeed, just retry N times before you abort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell git to retry if the http request failed?

No git itself, it does not support natively that feature.

But interestingly enough, the idea of wrapping a git command in order to retry its execution has been done before: see "[`git-retry`(1) Manual Page](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/git-retry.html) ", part of [depot_tools, a collection of tools for dealing with Chromium development](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools.html).

The [shell wrapper `git-retry`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git/+/01d2cde990f22d409e74e239de7e4d347102d6f6/git-retry) calls the python script [`git_retry.py`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git/+/01d2cde990f22d409e74e239de7e4d347102d6f6/git_retry.py) with the following options:

```
'-v', '--verbose', default=0,
```

> Increase verbosity; can be specified multiple times

```
'-c', '--retry-count', default=GitRetry.DEFAULT_RETRY_COUNT (5),
```

> Number of times to retry (default=5)

```
'-d', '--delay', default=GitRetry.DEFAULT_DELAY_SECS (3.0)
```

> Specifies the amount of time (in seconds) to wait between successive retries (default=3 sec.). This can be zero.

```
'-D', '--delay-factor', default=2
```

> The exponential factor to apply to delays in between successive failures (default=%default). If this is zero, delays will increase linearly. Set this to one to have a constant (non-increasing) delay.

---

Note: a git clone for a repo with submodule will always try to clone a submodule *twice* (one retry). See "[Is there any way to continue Git clone from the point where it failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38329327/6309)".

Comment: This solution doesn't do anything that a simple shell script does but adds a dependency on an external library

Answer (score 9):

You could run a script like this instead of calling git directly.

```
#!/bin/bash

REALGIT=/usr/bin/git

RETRIES=3
DELAY=10
COUNT=1
while [ $COUNT -lt $RETRIES ]; do
  $REALGIT $*
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    RETRIES=0
    break
  fi
  let COUNT=$COUNT+1
  sleep $DELAY
done
```

Comment: That’s my comment in code ;) – Exactly how I imagined it, nice!

Comment: I guess above solution would retry for `git grep ...`, too.

Comment: You should replace `$REALGIT $*` with `$REALGIT "$@"` according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314451/accessing-bash-command-line-args-vs

Answer (score 5):

[This](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/git-retry.html) is a wrapper around git commands, it recognizes when a command fails and retries

```
git retry [-v] [-c COUNT] [-d DELAY] [-e] — <git_subcommand>
```

More information on this can be found [here](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools.html).

Answer (score 4):

Run below command

> while ! git push; do sleep 7; done

Comment: I've put that in an alias as `really_fetch`, perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this as well because I wanted to make some of my scripts a bit more resilient toward network issues. I went for the bash retries as well and tried to make it as concise as possible.

I just wanted to leave my version here in case it helps anyone:

```bash
set -Eeuo pipefail

RETRIES_NO=5
RETRY_DELAY=3
for i in $(seq 1 $RETRIES_NO); do
  git my-maybe-failing-command && break
  sleep ${RETRY_DELAY}
  [[ $i -eq $RETRIES_NO ]] && echo "Failed to execute git cmd after $RETRIES_NO retries" && exit 1
done
echo "success"
```

It would also be very easy to write this as a function that you call with the command, retry-number, and delay to retry any kind of bash command that you want.