# How to retry when git clone fail?

Tags: git

Hey I have a shell script that git clone a repo in one of its steps,

But I noticed that git clone fails ramdomly, do we have anyway to retry when such random issue occur?

`git clone https://xxxxxx.git
Cloning into 'xxxx'...
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35014012/git-retry-if-http-request-failed) may be able to help you, or alternatively [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587536/is-there-any-way-to-continue-git-clone-from-the-point-where-it-failed). Give that a try.

Comment: Note: a git clone for a repo with submodule will always try to clone a submodule *twice* (one retry). See "[Is there any way to continue Git clone from the point where it failed?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38329327/6309)".

Comment: it is weird to suggest this but.. I was tryiing to clone from github and it was ultra slow 10KB/s for unreal engine project, even if using --depth=1. What I had to do was to wait til 23h (south america at least) and the download speed went up to 1.5MB/s! so may be the answer is: insistence or patience, until they implement cloning resume/continue capability :P

Answer (score 1):

Check the return code of the clone operation. You could also parameterize the number of times to retry instead of hardcoding to 5 below. You may nor may not want the sleep below.

```
   n=0
   until [ $n -ge 5 ]
   do
      git clone "$1" && break
      n=$[$n+1]
      sleep 1
   done
```

Invoke this script and pass an argument of the repo URL

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using git protocol?

```
git clone git:// urls for git protocol.
```