# How to resume a git pull/clone after a hung up unexpectedly?

Tags: git

I do a git pull/clone to some repository (mainly github ones).
Sometimes after a few minutes the download crashes.

Here is a log.

```
remote: Counting objects: 2284, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (713/713), done.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedlyiB | 5 KiB/s      
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

In my following of the process, i have noticed that i have already fetched about 4 MBs of objects.
When i start the process again, it starts from the beginning.
My Internet connection sucks, some times it crashes and i get disconnected unexpectedly.

My question is: Is there any way to resume the pull/clone to rescue those 4 MBs i have already fetched, and not to start again?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If a pull hung up, it will not write any changes to your filesystem. This is because, if it would, your local repository would not be in a stable state.

There is **no way to resume a pull/clone**. So your only choice is to pull/clone again.

Comment: But what about those 266 objects (in my example) already fetched ?? they are in the stable state right ?? I only need the other ones. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe some files, but not the whole repository. I'm sorry, but there is no way to get around to start again. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954852/how-to-complete-a-git-clone-for-a-big-project-on-an-unstable-connection

Comment: not real, if you git clone and interrupted just go to directory where .git is located then run git pull it will resume.

Comment: I don't see why this feature is not implemented. Its easy to check the integrity of downloaded pieces with file hashes !

Comment: I couldn't find official proofs, but from my recent experience, git clone **does** support resuming automatically.

Answer (score 4):

cd into the the main directory and run

```
git fetch
```

tested only on linux

Comment: But what if I'm download the repo for the first time? I won't be having the .git folder of the remote repo initially. `git fetch` won't work in that case. Any alternative solution?

Comment: @RewanthTammana It depends how far you were in the cloning process. Storm's answer worked well for my case. although I'm technically not sure if the Repo state was consistent after the crash.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking same that now files are useless no resumes :(, but actually git do have resume something like this:

```
// if git not init in resume directory
git init
// add origin first
git remote add origin <url>
// now you have to pull the branch that you were trying, git is intelligent enough to fetch remaining only
git pull <remote> <branch>
// then checkout to the branch you pulled
```

Answer (score 0):

A practical way is to fetch remtoe tag by tag. You can resume fetching from any hung up. Here's my script `gitclone.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

repo_url=$1
repo_dir=$(basename $repo_url)

mkdir -p $repo_dir
cd $repo_dir
git init
git remote add origin $repo_url

echo "Now will fetch remote chunk by chunk..."
tags=$(git ls-remote --tags --refs origin)
while read h t; do
        echo "fetching $t"
        git fetch origin $h
done <<< "$tags"

git pull
git switch master
```

Usage example:

```
$ ./gitclone.sh https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /work/llvm-project.git/.git/
Now will fetch remote chunk by chunk...
fetching refs/tags/llvmorg-1.0.0
remote: Enumerating objects: 67453, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9780/9780), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2069/2069), done.
remote: Total 67453 (delta 8648), reused 7711 (delta 7711), pack-reused 57673
Receiving objects: 100% (67453/67453), 9.72 MiB | 1.55 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (43765/43765), done.
From https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project
 * branch                      4df9396b4217bb9a0a39ea81f9d977014b64e491 -> FETCH_HEAD
fetching refs/tags/llvmorg-1.1.0
remote: Enumerating objects: 73269, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (10649/10649), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2194/2194), done.
Receiving objects:   2% (1466/73269), 260.00 KiB | 116.00 KiB/s
```