# Git repo sync - connection lost

Tags: android, git, android-source, repo

I'm trying to download android source (Cyanogenmod). i have spent more than 12hrs to download 2.5GB files, Now my connection lost for a while, it shows

```
 error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    fatal: early EOF
    fatal: index-pack failed
    fatal: unable to access 'https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/misc/': Could not resolve host: android.googlesource.com
    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_inputmethods_LatinIME/': Could not resolve host: github.com
    fatal: unable to access 'https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/misc/': Could not resolve host: android.googlesource.com
    error: Cannot fetch CyanogenMod/android_packages_inputmethods_LatinIME
    error: Cannot fetch platform/prebuilts/misc
    error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
```

Can i resume the download or i should download from the beginning, please help me to resume my download.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Once you have applied the fix that I describe below, you should simply re-run `repo sync` in order to resume and fully complete the resource synchronization process that was interrupted by these fatal errors.

The solution to the DNS-related error that you've encountered [`fatal: Could not resolve host`] is detailed on the **Known Issues** resolution page at Google's [AOSP Developer Site](http://source.android.com/source/known-issues.html#difficulties-syncing-the-source-tree-dns-issues). Apply this fix by adding the appropriate host entry for your remote repository `android.googlesource.com` inside your development machine's `/etc/hosts` config file. Begin by [clicking here](http://network-tools.com/nslook/Default.asp?domain=android.googlesource.com&type=1&server=67.222.132.213&class=1&port=53&timeout=5000&go.x=20&go.y=18) and [here](http://network-tools.com/nslook/Default.asp?domain=github.com&type=1&server=67.222.132.213&class=1&port=53&timeout=5000&go.x=19&go.y=7) to execute the IP address lookup tool provided by the free web resource: http://network-tools.com/nslook/.

Google's full description of this issue with detailed resolution I've included here:

> > **Difficulties syncing the source tree (DNS issues).**
> >
> > **Symptom**: When running repo sync, the process fails with various errors
> >     related to not recognizing the hostname. One such error is 
> >     `<urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>`.
> >     *EDIT: Another fatal error might be* `Could not resolve host`.
> >
> > **Cause**: Some DNS systems have a hard time coping with the high number
> >     of queries involved in syncing the source tree (there can be several
> >     hundred requests in a worst-case scenario).
> >
> > **Fix**: Manually resolve the relevant hostnames, and hard-code those
> >     results locally.
> >
> > > You can resolve them with the nslookup command, which will give you
> > >       one numerical IP address for each of those (typically in the "Address"
> > >       part of the output).

```
    $ nslookup googlesource.com
    $ nslookup android.googlesource.com
```

> > You can then hard-code them locally by editing /etc/hosts, and adding two
> >     lines in that file, of the form:

```
    aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd   googlesource.com
    eee.fff.ggg.hhh   android.googlesource.com
```

> > Note that this will only work as long as the
> >     servers' addresses don't change, and if they do and you can't connect
> >     you'll have to resolve those hostnames again and edit etc/hosts
> >     accordingly.

Comment: @Spartan The reason for the DNS fail is not really poorly configured DNS settings. It's the fact that `repo` rapidly generates many concurrent, duplicate DNS requests. Then, `repo` fatally fails because the DNS server response was judged to be too slow, i.e. did not respond.

Answer (score 0):

You [don't resume a clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14738344/6309), you can [try a shallow clone instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3957733/6309).

As mentioned here:

> `Error code 56` indicates a curl receive error of `CURLE_RECV_ERROR` which means there was some issue that prevented the data from being received during the clone process.
>   Typically this is caused by a network setting, firewall, VPN client, [or anti-virus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25448163/6309) that is terminating the connection before all data has been transferred.

You can know more with:

```
set GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
set GIT_TRACE=1
set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

You can try [changing `http.postBuffer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33210137/6309) or switching to ssh url clone.

Answer (score 0):

> Could not resolve host: android.googlesource.com

Which could be a DNS server problem. Try first [restarting your modem](https://www.labnol.org/tech/power-cycle-modem-router/23412/) in order to flush its DNS cache. If you're still seeing the problem, try [changing your Primary DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) to either one these two publicized DNS servers that Google operates:

- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4

Note that, if your Primary DNS has already been configured as described and you've also long-rebooted the router without resolution (pun intended), then adjusting your Primary DNS configuration to point at other public DNS servers is not likely to fix your situation. However, a reputable list of no-cost public servers [can be found here](https://www.lifewire.com/free-and-public-dns-servers-2626062).

Answer (score 0):

Spartan i checked the Cyanogenmod its working normally i prefer use internet download manager.i download 60mp and recall it.successfully fetched and resumed.