# Download big git repo in parts

Tags: git, git-svn

I am trying to download the [GCC Git repo](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GitMirror) and it is taking too much time due to download due to limited speed available.  I Just want to know that is it possible to download the repo in parts.

I have read many articles and questions relating to download single folder or part of repo specifically. But didn't find any article or question for downloading repo in parts. So, that I have all the commits available to me and Git on the same time can be update future commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [How to complete a git clone for a big project on an unstable connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954852/how-to-complete-a-git-clone-for-a-big-project-on-an-unstable-connection) you'll see it's not really possible right now. They propose [a couple of workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3957733/641451), but there's no warranty.

But, provided GCC has a [SVN repository](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SvnSetup), you can use `git-svn` as [explained here](http://blog.endpoint.com/2010/05/continuing-interrupted-git-svn-clone.html) to fetch SVN's content commit by commit:

```
$ git svn -s clone svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/desert69/gcc/.git/
r1 = b0439281e5f21d7567489ac582f45adfb813d332 (refs/remotes/trunk)
    A   gcc/config/m68k/xm-3b1.h
r2 = b24dd970fa8d03c1df555c4d771fa3dee00918de (refs/remotes/trunk)
    A   gcc/typeclass.h
r3 = 81e937b24b79225c9a61890f72737eba914dde22 (refs/remotes/trunk)
    A   gcc/config/m68k/x-apollo68
r4 = 0d9f9c476899983566408ee3698f097fa9d4ef5a (refs/remotes/trunk)
^C
$ cd gcc/
$ git svn fetch
    A   gcc/config/pyr/x-pyr
r5 = ff3c8016a7b2261c8df6c2564e76ad164b5a1a4a (refs/remotes/trunk)
    A   gcc/config/m68k/xm-crds.h
r6 = ff54129791033b73ffa49d12ec7802ca9b3010ea (refs/remotes/trunk)
(... goes on ...)
```

Sad to say `svn` makes it easier than `git`, but, well, that's it.

Comment: I agree, it's sad to hear that too.

Comment: @desert Thanks for the info, this is what I want for gcc it is really helping me as there are more 150K commits would take extra time but with no problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to download a truncated history with the --depth option:

```
--depth <depth>
       Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of
       revisions. A shallow repository has a number of limitations (you cannot clone or
       fetch from it, nor push from nor into it), but is adequate if you are only
       interested in the recent history of a large project with a long history, and
       would want to send in fixes as patches.
```

If you just want the files, do:

```
git clone --depth 1 <repo>
```

Comment: Yep.  And then iteratively `git fetch --depth=` a few hundred or thousand commits deeper each time until you've got the full history if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest might be to fire up an ec2 instance, clone the repo there and serve that with rsync. Even if you've used your free-micro-instance year a demand micro instance is $0.05/hr, its baseline 8GB disk is $0.88/mo and the traffic would probably fit in the free GB ($0.12/GB outbound after that).  Even if it took you a week to fetch that wouldn't add up to ten bucks.

Comment: What people tends to forget - and, at least for me, is a real problem - is that you need a credit card to pay for Amazon. I don't have - nor want to have - a credit card, and won't get it just to clone a git repo :)