# Is it possible to clone a GIT repo using a pre-downloaded archive of said repo?

Tags: git

I'm running into network issues because of a corporate proxy and large files in my initial repo, because of which I'm unable to clone my repo:

> error: RPC failed; curl 56 Failure when receiving data from the peer

All the solutions and workarounds I found are not working, but I had another thought:

I can download a zipped archive of my repo without issues. **Is it possible to prepare a repo folder with the zipped contents and then tell GIT to just link it to my repo?**

Looking at [How to clone git repository from its zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681643/how-to-clone-git-repository-from-its-zip), their solution relies on `clone --bare ...`, which which still downloads the large contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3957733/441662) from [How to complete a git clone for a big project on an unstable connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954852/how-to-complete-a-git-clone-for-a-big-project-on-an-unstable-connection) solved it for me:

> Use **shallow clone** i.e. git clone --depth=1, then **deepen** this clone
>   using git fetch --depth=N, with increasing N. You can use git fetch
>   --unshallow (since 1.8.0.3) to download all remaining revisions.

I did:

```
git clone ... --depth=1
git fetch --depth=2
git fetch --unshallow
```

And now I have everything.

---

As I can't delete my own question anymore since it has an answer, I voted to close my own question as a duplicate of said question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just do `git remote add` with file path to the repo directory.

Comment: A git fetch is still getting everything again from the remote. I'm doing `git init` in the unzipped folder, then `git remote add` followed by a `git fetch`. What am I missing?

Comment: Specify the remote you want to fetch from. By default it is the `origin` remote.

Comment: Yes, I did `git remote add origin <therepo>` so it fetches from origin, but it still fetches everything because it's not in my local repo and index, only in my workspace