# pushing and pulling changes to a remote after using "Download Copy"

Tags: git, git-clone, git-init

Let's say that I downloaded a copy of a git repo using the "Download Zip" option.  I started making changes, then realized that the rest of the world might like to have access to my work.  After I do a git init, what do I need to do to get the repo into the same state that it would have been, if I have used git clone from the start?

Comment: "Checkout" the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681643/how-to-clone-git-repository-from-its-zip).

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15682258/7976758