# Just download .git directory from github

Tags: python, git, http, github

When you execute `git init` in a new directory or an existing directory, Git creates a `.git` directory, where almost all the contents of the Git store and operation are located in the directory.
If you want to back up or copy a library, basically copy this directory to other places.

And now, I just want to download `.git` directory include contents from GitHub:

- I know the link like https://github.com/google/gson.git,
- then I can download the `.git` files through Python language using request. (I don't want to pass by git long command)

How do I find the .git directory from GitHub or my private gitlib and how to download it?

Comment: You can't do that, because the git server is designed to expect a git client speaking the git protocol. But you can use a library such as [GitPython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/) instead of forking `git clone`.

Comment: That is exactly what `git clone` is there for. So, what is your problem with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need only the .git content, you still need to use a git command:

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/<user>/<repo>
```

You will get a bare repo, one without working tree and only the .git content

See "[Python way to clone a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2472616/6309)" and [`gitpython-developers/GitPython`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython)

```
from git import Repo
Repo.clone_from(git_url, repo_dir, branch='master', bare=True)
```

With [**pygit2**](http://www.pygit2.org/repository.html), use [`pygit2.clone_repository`](http://www.pygit2.org/repository.html?highlight=clone_repository#pygit2.clone_repository):

```
clone_repository(url, path, bare=True)
```

Comment: I have another question, when I using git clone --bare to get the .git but some project was too large, dont resume from break point, I know using git fetch can resume the process, but it just get the FETCH_HEAD. I want to just get the all of .git files but also can resume, Is there any good way to solve it?

Comment: @zruibin to my knowledge, you cannot resume a fetch for *one* repo (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29192890/6309). You can indeed, when a clone is interrupted, make a git fetch. It should be enough for your .git bare repo folder to get all its files.