# Can't push to github a specific commit that added PNG Images

Tags: bash, github, push, commit

## Problem:

## Can't push to github a specific commit that added PNG Images

In git bash CLI, on Windows, `git push origin master` gets stuck on `Total 23 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)`, when I try push the response PNG images I added to the Online Portfolio Project for the Web Dev Front-End Nanodegree.

I tried what people suggested on several forums, by running on the CLI: `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`. It doesn't work..

Then, after `git add <all image files>`  I had to change the permissions to 100755, with with `git update-index --chmod=+x *`, on the images folder, because otherwise they would be set to `create mode 100644` when I would commit the files. After I did that, all the image files finally were indexed by the commit as `create mode 100755 images/img-xxxxxxxxxxx.png`, each.

Even after that, when i tried pushing the changes to the remote, it would still get stuck at `Total 23 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)`. But this time I went to sleep and, in the morning, there was the following answer on Bash CLI:

`$ git push
Enumerating objects: 25, done.
Counting objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
Writing objects: 100% (23/23), 3.98 MiB | 16.28 MiB/s, done.
Total 23 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ricardobossan/portfolio.git'`

But this time most of the commits were actually pushed to the remote, **except that the PNG images still were not there, which is really frustrating**.

And, worst of all, I still get stuck on the same message when I try to push changes: `Total 23 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)`..

Can anybody please help? I don't know what else to do.

Comment: What version of Git are you using? Can you try with the latest one? (2.20)

Comment: It worked!! Thanks so much @VonC! It took a few minutes, but it worked properly this time. =D

Comment: Great! I have added an answer illustrating that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the version of Git, it could be related to how Git is pushing.
Since it has changed in recent version (with the [introduction of Git wire protocol v2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51462372/6309)), it pays to try and upgrade to the latest version.

Namely the [Git for Windows 2.20](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.20.0.windows.1), with (for instance) the [`PortableGit-2.20.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.20.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.20.0-64-bit.7z.exe) archive that you can uncompress anywhere you want, and [add to your `PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53606336/6309).

The [OP ricardobossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8263573/ricardobossan) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732479/cant-push-to-github-a-specific-commit-that-added-png-images?noredirect=1#comment94352489_53732479):

> It worked!!
>   It took a few minutes, but it worked properly this time. =D

Comment: You're lifesaver! Spent hours trying to get around that issue.

Comment: @ricardobossan No problem. Don't forget to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.

Comment: I'll try to remember that from now on. Haven't much experience asking questions here yet...