# git clone and git push are stuck and won't end

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm new to git and I want to create a repo on gitlab. I've created a new project and added an ssh key. created a new directory in my Desktop. but when I use this command:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com ...
```

it shows:

> Cloning into ...

and nothing happens next. it stuck. but I can clone into other repo ( made by others on the internet). why I can't clone into my repo?

Comment: how big is the remote repo? how long did you wait?

Comment: it is only initialized with readme @mnagel

Comment: Is `git clone https://gitlab.com ...` literally the command you used? If yes, it has two problems. First, `https://gitlab.com` is not a valid repository url. It's expected to be `https://gitlab.com/foo/bar.git` where `foo` is your username or group name and `bar.git` is the repository name. Second, `...` would creates a local folder named `...` which is not a good name. If `...` is omitted, `bar` is the default name.

Comment: that is not literally what I use, it is git clone HTTP key

Comment: It sounds like your system is waiting to make the connection, i.e., the trouble is somewhere in your networking stack. Check that you can make a connection of the desired type (https, http, ssh, whatever protocol you've selected) to the server host, using whatever network-connection-diagnostic tools your system has.

Comment: Try `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git clone https://gitlab.com`. That should provide some additional debug output. It will likely confirm that something is blocking your connection to GitLab.com, as the last commenter suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Since [GitHub or GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51462372/6309) support the [v2 protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50273976/6309), you can get into these kind of deadlock with said v2.

Before Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), the on-the-wire protocol v2 easily falls into a deadlock between the `remote-curl` helper and the `fetch-pack` process when the server side prematurely throws an error and disconnects.

The communication has been updated to make it more robust.

See [commit b0df0c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0df0c16ead4c5512d506dcbbdf31194d992803c), [commit 0181b60](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0181b600a6deb66a346dbcbe8300cf9e2467ebbb), [commit 74b082a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74b082ad34fe2c727c676dac5c33d5e1e5f5ca56), [commit 101736a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/101736a14c9ad734fe24efed7513189849cd22eb), [commit dde72f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dde72f94bcba8f84f4ea6523b67302df6638c9c0) (19 May 2020), and [commit 04cc91a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04cc91abcbeea60f0ef25c041b412480cd2b1afe), [commit 51ca7f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51ca7f89f8de97388e4f7997ba07b71dffdb9178) (18 May 2020) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b37fd14](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b37fd14beb39b9f545bd72e42e1bdbb00bad4b3d), 09 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`stateless-connect`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0df0c16ead4c5512d506dcbbdf31194d992803c): send response end packet
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Force Charlie</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> Currently, `remote-curl` acts as a proxy and blindly forwards packets between an HTTP server and `fetch-pack`.
> In the case of a stateless RPC connection where the connection is terminated before the transaction is complete, `remote-curl` will blindly forward the packets before waiting on more input from fetch-pack.
> Meanwhile, `fetch-pack` will read the transaction and continue reading, expecting more input to continue the transaction.
>
> **This results in a deadlock between the two processes**.

(Hence your issue)

> This can be seen in the following command which does not terminate:
>
> ```
> $ git -c protocol.version=2 clone https://github.com/git/git.git --shallow-since=20151012
>   Cloning into 'git'...
> ```
>
> whereas the v1 version does terminate as expected:
>
> ```
> $ git -c protocol.version=1 clone https://github.com/git/git.git --shallow-since=20151012
>  Cloning into 'git'...
>  fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
> ```
>
> Instead of blindly forwarding packets, make `remote-curl` insert a response end packet after proxying the responses from the remote server when using `stateless_connect()`.
> On the RPC client side, ensure that each response ends as described.
>
> A separate control packet is chosen because we need to be able to differentiate between what the remote server sends and `remote-curl`'s control packets.
> By ensuring in the `remote-curl` code that a server cannot send response end packets, we prevent a malicious server from being able to perform a denial of service attack in which they spoof a response end packet and cause the described deadlock to happen.

So your case should not happen anymore with Git 2.28: if the clone has to fail, it will do so explicitily instead of staying "frozen" forever.

---

Note: with Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), the error message has been updated.

See [commit 8232a0f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8232a0ff48ce0959e20db9ffa1c4e16d4657dbec) (08 Jul 2021) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1e893a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e893a1216a1eec0e5e28e0a26098354e4d5a909), 28 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pkt-line`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8232a0ff48ce0959e20db9ffa1c4e16d4657dbec): replace "stateless separator" with "response end"
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> In [0181b60](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0181b600a6deb66a346dbcbe8300cf9e2467ebbb) (`pkt-line`: define PACKET_READ_RESPONSE_END, 2020-05-19, Git v2.28.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b37fd14beb39b9f545bd72e42e1bdbb00bad4b3d) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0313f36c6ebecb3bffe6f15cf25a4883100f0214)) (pkt-line: define `PACKET_READ_RESPONSE_END` 2020-05-19), the Response End packet was defined for Git's network protocol.
> When the patch was sent, it included an oversight where the error messages referenced "`stateless separator`", the work-in-progress name, over "`response end`", the final name chosen.
>
> Correct these error messages by having them correctly reference a "`response end`" packet.