# Remote Git branches not visible

Tags: git

After `git pull` I've always been able to see all branches by doing a `git branch`.

Right now (for some  reason) running `git branch` shows me master and one other branch, that I am actively working on,.

`git remote show origin` shows me all branches. If I do a `git checkout` on one of them, it pulls the branch down locally and swaps to it. After that it's visible when I run `git branch`

#### Question

How do I get the remote branches to display again when I run `git branch`?

*Note: This is only a visual problem - I can still access my remote branches without problems, I'm just wondering why they're not showing up when I do a git branch as they usually do*

Comment: For local edit/view you should create local branch from remote with git checkout -b <remote_name> origin/<remote_name>, another case remote branches from remote host with same name as local can rewrite local branch, so git doesn't create local branch from remote, you should add it yourself.

Comment: If you added `--single-branch` option when `git clone`, you won't see any other branch. Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17714718/1107242)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

TL;DR: just use `git branch -r` or `git branch -a` (after `git fetch` to update).  It's not at all clear why you've been seeing remote-tracking branches without these flags (perhaps you have been using a GUI that shows them automatically?).

You do, however, have at least one small misconception built in to your question—which is not surprising; this particular part of Git is tricky at first.

---

There are, in fact, *three* sets of branch names involved in this question.

> `git remote show origin` shows me all branches.

Not exactly.  Let's back up a bit, and define *two* sets (or classes, or whatever word you like to group them) of branches.  Git provides:

- Your regular, ordinary, local branches.  These are what `git branch` shows, when used with no arguments and flags.

  ```
  $ git branch
    diff-merge-base
  * master
    precious
    stash-exp
  ```

  The word "branch" often means one of these: a *name* that, when fed to `git rev-parse`, resolves to a commit ID:

  ```
  $ git rev-parse diff-merge-base
  2d0cc5001c1a88995727521d4ef77f7a4acc4e14
  ```

  and whose full name starts with `refs/heads/`:

  ```
  $ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name diff-merge-base
  refs/heads/diff-merge-base
  ```
- Your *remote-tracking branches*.  These are what `git branch -r` shows:

  ```
  $ git branch -r
    origin/HEAD -> origin/master
    origin/maint
    origin/master
    origin/next
    origin/pu
    origin/todo
  ```

The key difference between these is that your local branches are your names to manipulate however you like, while your remote-tracking branches are your names that Git automatically slaves to something else.  It is *possible* for you to manipulate them yourself, but it's not *profitable*, as their intent is to remember some *other* Git's branch names (and corresponding SHA-1 values).

Note that feeding a remote-tracking branch name to `git rev-parse` *also* works, and you can get its `symbolic-full-name` as well: this simply begins with `refs/remotes/`, followed by the name of the remote, followed by the *local* name *as seen if you're the Git running **on** the remote*.  Hence:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name origin/master
refs/remotes/origin/master
```

means that my Git's `origin/master` is my Git's *memory* of what `master` meant, on `origin`, the last time had my Git call up `origin` and fetch—i.e., update—from them.

#### `git remote` (sometimes) actually calls up the remote Git

Remember that there are *two* (or sometimes even more) Git version-control databases involved any time you fetch or push commits.  So you can look at *your* information, or you can ask your Git to call up *their* Git, over the Internet-phone, and query *them* about *their* information.  They, too, may have local branches, and even remote-tracking branches, of their own.  (Usually, for situations like this, they have only local branches.)

For illustration purposes, let me delete one of my own remote-tracking branches (this is pretty harmless since I will run `git fetch` in a moment to restore it):

```
$ git branch -r -d origin/pu
Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/pu (was 7c79844).
```

Now if I run `git branch -r` I will no longer have an `origin/pu`: my Git no longer has that as a remote-tracking branch.  But *their* Git, over on `origin`, still has a *local* branch named `pu`, so:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
  Push  URL: git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    maint  tracked
    master tracked
    next   tracked
    pu     new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    todo   tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master    merges with remote master
    stash-exp merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (local out of date)
```

When I run `git remote show origin`, my Git calls up their Git (this happens to be a copy of the Git repository for Git—there's another one on github.com that is probably more appropriate these days) and gets from them a list of all their branches.  I already have most of them as my own "remote-tracking branches", but I deleted `pu`, so it shows as "new".

A similar command, `git ls-remote`, also calls up the other Git and queries it, but shows you more: it shows you the commit hash that goes with each branch (and the object hash for each tag as well).  There are a lot of tags, so let me restrict this to just one branch:

```
$ git ls-remote origin master
e05806da9ec4aff8adfed142ab2a2b3b02e33c8c        refs/heads/master
```

In both these cases, your Git (or my Git) calls up their Git and gets information from them, but it merely displays it, rather than *saving* it.  To *save* the information, we must run `git fetch`.  I have not run this in a little while, so:

```
$ git fetch origin
remote: Counting objects: 2064, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1294/1294), done.
remote: Total 2064 (delta 1383), reused 1118 (delta 767)
Receiving objects: 100% (2064/2064), 2.12 MiB | 2.29 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1383/1383), done.
From git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git
   de2efeb..e05806d  master     -> origin/master
   3074f94..c69c2f5  next       -> origin/next
 * [new branch]      pu         -> origin/pu
   1a46792..2135c1c  todo       -> origin/todo
```

This `git fetch` did the same thing as `git remote show` and `git ls-remote`, but then also did more things: it collected the *objects* I need to complete *my* repository, then updated *my* remote-tracking branch names to correspond to the branch names in *their* repository.

This is why I regained `origin/pu`: they still have a `pu`, and I discarded mine, so I obtained theirs and now have one again.

This is also why I updated all the others except `maint`: it's been long enough that they have all been updated.  My `origin/master` used to refer to commit `de2efeb`, but now it refers to `e05806d`, which is the same ID we saw above when we ran `git ls-remote`.  (This means they did not update their `master` in the several minutes it took me to type all this in.  Imagine that, *billions* of nanoseconds have gone by without an update! :-) )

(Note that `git remote show -n origin` *skips* the phoning-up of `origin`, and simply shows you what your Git has recorded.  Several other `git remote` commands also work locally; consult the documentation for specifics.)

#### Summary

To recap, then, there are *three* sets of branch names involved here:

- Your local branches;
- Your remote-tracking branches; and
- Their branches (in the remote Git).

The last set of branch names *don't matter, most of the time*.  Most of the time, you work in your own repository.  There's only one Git involved, and it's yours.  *Their* Git, which has its own branches, is right out of the picture.

But sometimes—ah, such times!—sometimes, you must connect your Git to *another* Git.  *Now* their names matter!  The really tricky thing here is that your names don't *have* to match their names *at all*.  There's no hard and fast reason *your* `master` *must* correspond to their `master`—but *your* Git will copy *their* `master` to *your* `origin/master`, so it saves a lot of brain cells if your names and their names *do* match up.  You *can* work around this (in multiple different ways), but don't do it until you have a situation that really calls for it (with multiple remotes that use conflicting branch names—this almost never happens).

#### What about `git checkout blah`?

You noted above that:

> If I do a `git checkout` on one of [their branch names that I don't see in `git branch` output], it pulls the branch down locally and swaps to it.

Let's say that you have run `git branch -r` (rather than `git remote show origin`) and seen a branch named `origin/zorg`.  Let's also say you don't already have a (local) branch named `zorg`.  You run:

```
$ git checkout zorg
```

and your Git says:

```
Branch zorg set up to track remote branch zorg from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'zorg'
```

Your Git hasn't "pulled down" *anything* here.  What it's done is to create a new local branch name, `zorg`, pointing to the same *commit*—the same big ugly SHA-1 hash ID—as `origin/zorg`.  That commit was already in your repository, ready to be checked out any time, and in fact you could have done:

```
$ git checkout origin/zorg
```

to look at it—but that would give you what Git calls a "detached HEAD".

What's going on here is that in Git, a branch *name* is merely a moveable pointer to *one specific commit*.  The `git checkout` command, when used this way, does *two* things: check out the one specific commit (into the work-tree), *and*, switch your Git's notion of the "current branch name".  When you `git checkout` an existing, local, ordinary branch name, Git checks out the one commit in question, and puts you "on the branch", as `git status` will say:

```
$ git status
On branch master
```

When you `git checkout` any commit by something that's *not* a simple branch name, Git still checks out the one commit, but *takes you off of any branch*, i.e., gives you a "detached HEAD".

We know from the above that `origin/master` is (now) commit `e05806da9ec4aff8adfed142ab2a2b3b02e33c8c`, so:

```
$ git checkout origin/master
```

or:

```
$ git checkout e05806da9ec4aff8adfed142ab2a2b3b02e33c8c
```

both do the same thing.  Since `origin/master` is *not* a *local* branch, I end up with:

```
$ git status
HEAD detached at e05806d
```

(or sometimes `HEAD detached at origin/master`).

Hence, what `git checkout` does is attempt to convert the name you gave it to a branch name.  *If that fails*, `git checkout` has this extra built-in feature: it searches through all your *remote-tracking branches* to see if there's exactly one that "mostly matches" the name.  So `git checkout zorg` checks for a local branch named `zorg`, fails to find it, then searches all your remote-tracking branches for one that *also* matches `zorg`.  There is in fact exactly one—`origin/zorg`—so this triggers the special case code.

The special case code simply implements "create new local branch set up to track corresponding remote-tracking branch".  That is, create a local `zorg`, with its *upstream* (as Git now calls these things) set to `origin/zorg`.

Note that for this to work, there must be *exactly one* suitable remote-tracking branch.  If I did not have `origin/zorg` at all, this would fail—and if I had both `origin/zorg` and `thirdrepo/zorg`, where `thirdrepo` is another remote, like `origin` but pointing to some third Git repository, it would also fail, because Git would not know whether my local `zorg` should have `origin/zorg` or `thirdrepo/zorg` as its upstream.

Most of the time, you have only one remote, named `origin`.  So, as long as you have all of `origin`'s branches saved as your own Git's remote-tracking branch memories, you can just `git checkout` those names to get your Git to create them.  But sometimes you will find that you must run `git fetch` first, so as to update your remote-tracking branches.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very well written and excellent answer. It cleared up a lot of things for me!

Comment: Great answer, thank you for the time spent on writing it.

Comment: Incredible answer, I learned so much from reading this.  Thank you

Comment: Thanks for putting your time and writing such an incredible answer

Answer (score 68):

Well, I had the exact same problem, then I find that in project-specific git config (located at ./.git/config)

`remote.origin.fetch`

was something other than

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Something like:

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = https://....
  fetch = +refs/heads/v8.1:refs/remotes/origin/v8.1
```

After changing it to:

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = https://....
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

now 'git branch -avv' show all remote tracking branches

If you like to know from where I got this weird settings, it is because i used 'clone --single-branch'

Comment: you may need to do ```git fetch --all``` after changing git config file

Comment: This solved my similar problem, even though my repository came from `git clone --depth=1 --no-checkout`.

Comment: I had a similar problem where I cloned a bare repo, then used `git worktree` to work on different branches on parallel. For some reason, the `[remote "origin"]` config section did not have the `fetch` entry at all, which (I presume) completely prevented git from creating remote tracking branches at all (and therefore, I was unable to set tracking branch information on my local clone). Adding the missing entry `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` fixed it for me!

Comment: When `git clone`, you added `--single-branch` option, so you can not see any other branches. Your solution is definitely correct.

Comment: This solution came in clutch, I was able to pull remote branches but not see them in lists. Turns out my config file, for some reason, was set to `fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`.

Comment: I had this issue with a fork and many branches, good tip, in my case this solve that problem thanks!

Comment: This seems like it could be a common issue with using installer scripts for projects like NvChad. Thanks!

Comment: This happened to me after `git clone --depth=X` (shallow clone, which only includes the main branch) followed by `git fetch --unshallow` - which removes the depth limit but *does not* make this adjustment to the remote.

Answer (score 9):

1) just show branches:

```
git branch -r
```

2) load remote branches into local git:

```
git fetch origin/<remote_name>
```

3) create local branch from remote branch (after call it you can view branch into out of git branch):

```
git checkout -b <remote_name> origin/<remote_name>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. There's probably dozens or hundreds of branches on remote that I can see in the github UI, but I only see origin/HEAD and origin/main

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the same scenario but executing just `git fetch` command is fetched all the branches in master.

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch -a
```

will list all the branches, the remotes one will appear in red prefixed by the name of the remote.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try [get-fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) as:

```
git fetch <remote>
```

Comment: Question is about viewing remotes using `git branch`

Answer (score 0):

git branch

o/p : master
xyz

git branch -u origin/[branch Name]

ex : git branch -u origin/developer

Then checkout  :
 git checkout [branch Name]

ex : git checkout sonarfix-fvfr-parts-splitter

git branch

o/p : master
xyz
developer

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is the perfect one and solved my purpose. I'm just sharing what worked for me. 
Let's start with problem, I was trying to access a branch named 'NewBranch' that I have already created but I got an error, something like this:

```
error: pathspec 'NewBranch' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

So, I tried this git command,

```
git remote show origin
```

The above command will give you the list of all branches. And, I found that the branch I am trying to checkout is new and not fetched yet. Something like this,

```
  Remote branches:
DH5982                               new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
ML                                   tracked
Sarvesh_Branch                       tracked
NewBranch                   new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
auc_branch                           tracked
fileSize                             tracked
fileuploadtime                       tracked
master                               tracked
refs/remotes/origin/DH-5697          stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
refs/remotes/origin/DH-5914          stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
```

So, I simply used this git command,

```
git fetch --all
```

And, then its done, and 'NewBranch' became accessible to me.