# How to resume clone git code while Internet connection is available?

Tags: git

I'm trying clone large repo code and my internet connection break at the middle of clone process. How can I resume clone process? Is there any possibility to solve this issue?

It displaying error like that :-

```
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: A workaround could be to use a download manager to manually download the repo to a local folder. Then clone it, and manually change the location of the remote repo in the git config.

Comment: So You mean there is no any solution? I'm a developer and client doesn't provide me File manager details to download manually code. I have only git access.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems git clone does not support resuming. You will need to try some workaround, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954852/how-to-complete-a-git-clone-for-a-big-project-on-an-unstable-connection

Comment: @airos. Let me check. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Although resuming capabilities for git clone have been discussed https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg269766.html,

> There is currently no way to resume a git clone using git, but there
>   is a neat trick you can use instead of cloning directly -- using git
>   bundle files.
>   ([The Linux Kernel Archives](https://www.kernel.org/cloning-linux-from-a-bundle.html))

The bundle approach used for the linux kernel seems the best option if you have access to the repo (or know someone who does) https://www.kernel.org/cloning-linux-from-a-bundle.html

See [How to complete a git clone for a big project on an unstable connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954852/how-to-complete-a-git-clone-for-a-big-project-on-an-unstable-connection) for other possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check.