# Pause/Resume cloning of a repo

Tags: git, git-clone

During the work from home days, my bandwidth is falling short to clone a repo. I've tried around 10 times to clone the repo, no luck.

```
Receiving objects:  91% (54330/59387), 445.67 MiB | 44.00 KiB/s
Receiving objects:  91% (54506/59387), 445.80 MiB | 46.00 KiB/s
Receiving objects:  91% (54635/59387), 445.86 MiB | 45.00 KiB/s
Receiving objects:  92% (54637/59387), 445.86 MiB | 45.00 KiB/s
Receiving objects:  92% (54721/59387), 445.92 MiB | 38.00 KiB/s
Receiving objects:  92% (54782/59387), 445.99 MiB | 43.00 KiB/s
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Is there any way I could receive the remaining ~8% of the objects? Let me know if there are any attributes of git clone that could help me with this. I am okay even if there is a way in Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code to achieve the same.

I have seen ["How to complete a git clone for a big project on an unstable connection?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954852/how-to-complete-a-git-clone-for-a-big-project-on-an-unstable-connection). It explains how to do if you are about to begin from the start again. What I am looking for is how to move ahead without restarting the clone.

Comment: About your last sentence : if the clone fails, `git` (unfortunately in your case) cleans up whatever it had locally, so there is no "resuming" (not using `git` only at least). Are you in a situation where you have a part of the repo's history locally ?

Comment: @LeGEC: Agreed. No I don't have partial history local .

Comment: The suggestion is : try to download a smaller starting payload (using `git clone --depth 1`), and increase little by little, until a complete fetch passes.

Answer (score 3):

Try to start with a shallow clone :

```
git clone --depth 1 <repo>
```

You may then try to unshallow the repo :

```
git fetch --unshallow origin
```

If it fails, you can try to first increase the depth iteratively :

```
git fetch --depth 10 origin master
git fetch --depth 20 origin master
...
```

and possibly fetch branches one by one :

```
git fetch --depth 1 origin branch1
git fetch --depth 10 origin branch1
...
```

until `git fetch --unshallow` passes.

---

Another way is to just copy the files from any existing clone.

Say you have an ssh access to a server which doesn't have bandwidth problems :

```
ssh <server-with-bandwidth>
[remote]$ git clone <repo>
```

You then just need to copy the content of `remote:repo/` (including its `.git/` directory, which contains all the cloned history) over to your own PC.

You can use `scp`, `sftp`, `rsync` ... or any tool which allow resuming on failure.

Obviously, follow your company's security guidelines : choose a remote server on which it is valid to clone the code, remove the useless clone after it's been used, etc ...