I want to pull or clone code from GitHub, there is an error occur while pull or clone
$ git pull https://github.com/ZAHIDKHATTAKCS/Final-Year-Project.git
remote: Enumerating objects: 912, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (278/278), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (172/172), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 0
error: 8114 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

I just try to pull my final year project from git to local:

I tried pull command
also tried clone command


I think I have seen "unexpected disconnect" before - can you try a different connection to the internet?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954852/how-to-complete-a-git-clone-for-a-big-project-on-an-unstable-connection , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618885/error-rpc-failed-curl-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining
