# How can I remove the working copy from a Mercurial clone?

Tags: mercurial, repository, clone, working-copy, bare

When cloning a repository with mercurial you can pass the -U/--noupdate flag to create a clone with no working copy. Can I remove the working copy if I forget to pass this flag at clone time? And if so, how?

This is conceptually similar to [this git question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/git-convert-normal-to-bare-repository), but for mercurial.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Documentation at Mercurial wiki says following about bare repositories:

> "*Although this is a minor issue, Mercurial can obviously handle a
>   bare repository; that is, a repository without a working copy. In Git
>   you need a configuration option for that, whereas in Hg you only need
>   to check out the null revision, like this:*"
>
> ```
> hg update null
> ```

The null revision is similar to the empty state you have when you have just done `hg init`. It is the parent of revision 0 (and the second parent of all non-merge revisions) and by updating back to it you again get an empty working copy.

The link may look ironic:

- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GitConcepts

Comment: Aha! That does the trick. RTFM. Or in this case RTFW. I had read "hg clone --help", which does hint at this solution... but only if you know the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @rq: It happens to all of us. I have a number of moments of RTFM every week.

Comment: If there are files still left over, `hg purge` may help to get rid of them.

Comment: From TortoiseHg Workbench, you can accomplish this via `Repository` > `Update` and specifying `null` as the `Update to:`

Answer (score -24):

```
rm -rf *
```

This removes all "visible" files (under *nix). Since the Mercurial repository is stored in the "hidden" file `.hg`, it won't be touched. Unfortunately, neither will any hidden files of your own, such as `.hgignore`.

To restore the working copy, I'm sure there's an `hg update` flag that works, but this will as well:

```
hg revert --all
```

Comment: -1 Totally not right. This is what I tried, and marks the whole working copy as "!" deleted, which can mess up pushes and pulls.

Comment: @rq - perhaps you should have said that in your original question. Personally, I have no idea why you'd want to copy a repository without a working directory. Running a lot of pushes and pulls without attempting to build in-between is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: one use is to create a backup copy of a local clone on a network drive, using a commit hook that automatically pushes to the backup.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to have a local working copy when, for instance, serving a mercurial repository from a web-server.