# Mercurial - convert normal repo to bare repo

Tags: mercurial, repository, tortoisehg

i´ve installed TortoiseHg with Mercurial. Another programmer of our department created a "normal" hg repo a few months ago. Now I have to change this repo into a "bare" one. Is this even possible?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158726/how-can-i-remove-the-working-copy-from-a-mercurial-clone

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To create a bare repo when cloning use the no update flag when cloning i.e. 
`hg clone --noupdate ...`

To convert to a bare repo update to the "null" branch use 
`hg update null`

Comment: that works fine for me, thank you. "hg update null" on central repo deletes all files, excepting the ".hg" directory.

Comment: Good answer! Small detail: `null` is not a branch, is the changeset before the first changeset you make (the ancestor of the first revision).