# git - can't delete file permanently from repository

Tags: git

I'm trying to delete some huge, 100MB binary file from my repository.
I followed these instructions, detailed here:

http://stevelorek.com/how-to-shrink-a-git-repository.html

The instructions are based on the command:

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' --prune-empty -f -- --all
```

When I ran the script again, after allegedly removing the file, it was indeed gone.
But then, when I cloned the repository again, after pushing the changes, the file was back again.

How can I apply the changes after deleting the big file?

```
git push origin --force --all
```

simply won't cut it.

EDIT: The file has been deleted 2 years ago, so there's nothing to commit/delete.
I tried creating a dummy commit with some file addition, still no go.

Comment: Why won't `git push origin --force --all` "cut it"?  That *is* how you "apply the changes".

Comment: My guess would be you've got tags on the remote that still reference commits with that file in their histories.

Comment: Did you commit after deleting the file? Push only uploads what is commited

Comment: The file has been deleted 2 years ago :) There is nothing to commit...

Comment: I'm 99% sure we didn't use tags that early... Besides, shouldn't this method also affect the tags?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up converting the local, clean repository into a bare repository, [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-git-repository-from-normal-to-bare) and replacing the old bare repository with it.

Still no idea as to why I couldn't apply the changes to the central repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BGF](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to do such cleanups.

Simply pushing the new cleaned commits, will not clean the other repository as long the old commits are still reachable.