# Gitblit "this repository has a working copy and cannot receive pushes" when create new repository

Tags: git, gitblit

As title, when I create a new repository using WebUI tool from gitblit I got this problem.

I tried all type of solution:

- Create a repository with anonymous read/write.
- Create a repository with authentication read/write.

After created, I try to force push but got this error

The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing http://mygitserver.com/git/folder/mygitrepo.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed

Now I cannot do anything with my repository.

**Notes: All existed repositories are working normal.**

Comment: The answer accepted of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-normal-git-repository-to-a-bare-one worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Check the local config of that repo on the server:

```
git/folder/mygitrepo.git/config
```

See if `core.bare` is set to `false` or missing (it should be set to `true`).