# Clone multiple existing Gerrit repositories to Gitlab

Tags: migration, clone, gitlab, gerrit, repository

we are migrating from Gerrit Code Review to GitLab in our office. I know how to clone one repository from Gerrit to GitLab. But in our office server we have around 50 or so repositories. I have tried transferring the repositories manually to GitLab's 'repositories' directory and then importing, but it only creates bare repositories. I'd like to know if there's a way to clone all the repositories in one go. Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it only creates bare repositories

That is what GitLab manages, as a Git Hosting service: bare repos that you can clone locally.

You could move those non-bare repo by:

- moving only the `.git` of your existing repo to GitLab repo folder, where each `.git` is renamed after the repo it was in:

  ```
  repo1/.git => /home/git/repositories/repo1.git
  repo2/.git => /home/git/repositories/repo2.git
  repo2/.git => /home/git/repositories/repo3.git
  ```

If you are talking about two different servers (hopefully both with the same OS), I would recommend `tar cpvf repo1.git.tar /tmp/repo1.git`: move in `/tmp` and rename first, then tar, and copy over that tar to the new server.

- [transform those repos into bare one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200662/6309):

  ```
  cd /tmp/repo1.git && git config --bool core.bare true
  ```
- Try the [Import process of GitLab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/wiki/Import-existing-repositories-into-GitLab) (but there seems to be a bug in progress on that: [issue/pull 5005](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/5005)

  bundle exec rake gitlab:import:repos RAILS_ENV=production

---

While the import process command is correct, the [OP redmoses](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2894655/redmoses) mentions in the comments:

> If I just copy the repositories to `/home/git/repositories`, then the repositories appear in GitLab with no source files or no record of previous commits done in Gerrit.
>
> To make this work this is what I did:
>
> - Created a new directory inside the repositories directory
> - Copied all the repos from Gerrit (was located in `/usr/local/gerrit2/git`) to the new directory.
> - Then just simply ran GitLab's import process GitLab then created a group called "`Dev`" and imported the existing repositories perfectly.
>
> And I didn't need to convert the repositories to bare.

Comment: If I just copy the repositories to /home/git/repositories then the repositories appear in GitLab with no source files or no record of previous commits done in Gerrit. To make this work this is what I did -

 - Created a new directory inside the repositories directory
 - Copied all the repos from Gerrit (was located in /usr/local/gerrit2/git) to the new directory.
 - Then just simply ran GitLab's import process

GitLab then created a group called "Dev" and imported the existing repositories perfectly. And I didn't need to convert the repositories to bare. Thanks anyways

Comment: @redmoses Sounds great. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.