# Creating a remote Git repository and populating it with files already stored in the remote location

Tags: git, remote-server, git-remote

I'm new to Git and I'm going to start developing new modules for an existing web application. This application is currently hosted on a web server and I would like to use Git as a versioning tool. I have created a new bare repository using `git init --bare newdev.git` but I don't know how to add the files which are already on the server.

Thank you.

Comment: Um... why are you making bare repository?

Comment: I just followed the docs. Can I create a simple `git init` in the existing sources folder and then clone that repository on my local machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whoa, hold on there.  Let's back up some.  You're "new to git" so you need some basics! :-)

For your purposes, there are two kinds of repositories:

- A "regular" repo, in which you work.  You and everyone else make your own versions of these.
- A "bare" repo, which is used only for you and other people to *coordinate* work.  There is only one of these.

A "bare" repository has no place in which anyone *can* do any work.  That's what makes it "bare"—and what makes it a safe place to "push" to.  The problem with pushing to some non-bare repo is this (git actually stops you, with `error: refusing to update ...`, but it's what the problem *would* be if git let you do it):

1. Alice is working in her repo.  She checks out some branch and edits file `config`.
2. Bob is working in his repo.  He checks out the same branch and also edits `config`.
3. Bob finishes editing `config` first, and pushes his changes to Alice.
4. Alice's changes are wiped out, replaced with Bob's changes.  Ouch!

By not letting anyone work "in" it, a bare repository sidesteps this problem.

There's still one other problem, which is: how do you get this thing—the bare repo—started in the first place?  It has no place to work!

The answer is: you don't start there, you start with your own repo, that nobody else has a copy of.  You write some initial version in there.  Then you create a new bare repo, on the shared server, by *copying* the one you had:

```
sharedserver$ cd /place/where/bare/repos/go
sharedserver$ git clone --bare ssh://cosmins.machine.name/path/to/initial project.git
```

Now "sharedserver" has the bare repo in `/place/where/bare/repos/go/project.git`, and you (and Alice and Bob and so on) can all `git clone` that.

(The "shared server" can be something like github, which has a different method of creating the shared repo from your original initial non-shared one.  I don't use github and can't really say anything about that.)

(It is possible to convert a regular, non-bare, repo into a bare one, or vice versa, but it's a bit of a pain.  Just create the bare one by `git clone --bare`.)

---

Another method of side-stepping the "work gets overwritten" problem is not to use `push` at all.  If everyone co-operates in a peer to peer sharing system, then Alice can `pull` from Bob and Cosmin, and Bob can `pull` from Alice and Cosmin, and so on.  Note that this results in a very large number of people to `pull` from, though, which is why shared-servers come about.  You can all just meet there, instead of always having to go to each others' homes.

Comment: Ok, but in this project the files are already on the server and the site is up and running. This is why I was saying that I need to create a repo and add the existing files.

Comment: "The files are already on the server": but not in a git repo, correct?  So you need to create a (non bare) repo, make some commit(s), and only then start doing the whole bare-clone-on-server thing.  You can make the non-bare initial repo on the server too, it does not matter where you clone *from*.

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is just `git init` (no --bare) in the folder where the existing files are.

Then `git add .` (or `git add filename.ext` for individual files). Finally `git commit`.

Once you have your files committed, you can use `git clone` to get the repository onto another machine, probably through an ssh url, like `git clone ssh://example.com/path/to/repo/.git ./`

---

Edit from comments:

You cannot `push` from one repository to another if both are on the same branch. You have three options:

1. Check out a different branch on the repository you are trying to push to
2. Make the repository you are trying to push to a "bare" repository
3. `pull` changes from the source repository to the target repository

Out of the three options, option #3 is the most common practice when using git.

Option #2 is more similar to non-distributed systems like Subversion, or git systems with an "authoritative" copy of the code, like Github.com.

Option #1 is really a hack and shouldn't be used unless you really have no other choice.

---

To create a bare repository from an existing one, you can either manually convert the repository in place ([existing SO question w/good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200662/814835)), or you can `git clone --bare /path/to/my_repo/.git ./my_repo.git` to create a new clean bare repository. I would recommend the second option, it is much safer/cleaner to do and you don't mess up your existing repository, but you can do whatever seems best.

Comment: Did that, got the error I pasted in the previous answer.

Comment: You need to delete the original .git repo you created in your question. I think that is the problem.

Comment: I already deleted the bare repository and created another one. Same error.

Comment: I see. Can you help me with number (2) ?

Comment: Updated answer again with more instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, git init in the sources folder, add the files you want to the repository then clone the repository to the local machine. Since you already created a bare repository you should move the .git folder out of the way and you can delete it in the end when you are sure you don't need it.

Comment: Eric, I tried this already. I get this error:

`remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master[K
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository[K
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent[K
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match[K
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.[K`

Comment: If you already cloned it, move that out of the way or delete it as well and clone it again from scratch.