# Git upstream repo is staging pushed changes (trying to delete added files, undoing added lines)

Tags: git

At my workplace, we are using a ["Forking Workflow"](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-forking).

For some odd reason, when I push changes from **my** local to **my** public repo, the public repo updates to the correct revision, however stages the changes I made in the opposite way. (I.E. "added" files become "deleted" on the stage)

What could be causing this?

Comment: Doesn't your team use git hook for some purpose ? I suspect it changes your staging state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was pushing to a non-bare repo. (And had turned off the warning I get when I do so)

What happens The public repo gets updated, but the public repo's "working directory" was still the same way from before the commit.

Solution: If there is no work being done on the public repo, it needs to be a ["bare" repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-git-repository-from-normal-to-bare).