# Restore git clone local copy as a shared repository

Tags: git, git-branch

I've backed up my repository using git clone.  I've used the commands described here to restore it:

[How to convert a normal Git repository to a bare one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-git-repository-from-normal-to-bare)

My original shared repository had  many branches.  e.g.

```
git branch -a
* master
branch1
branch2
```

However the the shared repository restored from the back up, all the branches are missing

```
git branch -a 
* master
remotes/origin/branch1
remotes/origin/branch2
```

Are there any steps I should do to restore the branches in my shared repository that's restored from a clone

Comment: Check `git branch -r`, you'll find the branches are there.

Comment: I forgot to list the remote branches in the rested shared repository.  Thanks for that.  I understand that the branches are there, but how do I restore them in the restored repository?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of some other question involving "missing" (hint: not really missing) branches in fresh Git clones.

Comment: Duplicate of [Clone all remote branches with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/clone-all-remote-branches-with-git)

Answer (score 1):

This command

```
git branch -a 
* master
remotes/origin/branch1
remotes/origin/branch2
```

shows that the branches are still in your repository, they're just remote-tracking branches under `.git/refs/remotes/origin/`, instead of regular local branches under `.git/refs/heads/`.

Just create local copies under `.git/refs/heads/` like you would with any other kind of branch:

```
git branch branch1 remotes/origin/branch1
git branch branch2 remotes/origin/branch2
```

### Documentation

Here is the syntax for creating branches (from the [official git-branch(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html, truncated for brevity):

```
git branch <branchname> [<start-point>]
```

The `<start-point>` can be, among other things, any kind of branch reference, or a commit sha.