# Is it OK to use `git push` to restore a remote repository?

Tags: git

Suppose we have just lost a remote repository, because someone accidentally typed the following command.

```
rm -rf OurRepo.git
```

In order to restore it, we plan to use one of the [top-voted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-git-repository-from-normal-to-bare) to an earlier question.

However, I observed that none of the solutions mentions the following three-step strategy.

1. Use `git init --bare` to recreate the remote repository.
2. Set the new remote `git remote add origin <new repository URL>`.
3. Use `git push origin master` from one of the machines that has an up-to-date copy of the repo

I have tried this on a toy respository and it **appears** to work, but one of my colleagues claims there is a problem with it without being able to pinpoint why.

Can anyone either confirm or deny whether this is a reasonable way to restore a lost remote?

Comment: The end result would be the remote repo having the same objects as yours. Should work just fine.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, Would it have any negative (especially unexpected) side effects though, compared to one of the two answers I linked?

Comment: I can't think of any off the top of my head. But should there be any side effects, they'd be recoverable easily with a `git config`. The important part, the objects, will contain exactly the same data.

Comment: You didn't link to any answers, only the question. Also, your proposed strategy sounds just fine, though don't forget to push any tags with `git push origin --tags` as well. Your coworker says there's a problem but won't say exactly what that problem is?

Comment: @Cupcake, He does not remember. I mentioned the top voted answers on the question.

Comment: The linked question is different to your stated requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there shouldn't be anything wrong with your proposed strategy, and in fact this would be a typical way to restore a remote repository (though not the only way).

Don't forget to push your tags along with your branches:

```
git push origin --tags --all
```

That command will push all branches under `.git/refs/heads/` and all tags under `.git/refs/tags/`. If you don't want to push all of your branches, just name each branch you want to push instead of using `--all`.

You'll probably want to avoid using `--mirror` in this case, because that will push **all** references under `.git/refs/`, which will include remote-tracking branches in your local repo, which you probably don't need or want on your remote.

### Alternatives

The other alternative to using `git push` to restore a remote would just be to clone a new remote from another repo with the `--bare` option:

```
git clone --bare <otherRepo> <newRepoName>
```

### Documentation

- [Official git-push(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html)
- [Official git-clone(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html)