# Is it possible to pull or clone from the cloned git repo?

Tags: git

Okay will explain ;) I have a repo say, sample.git (BARE) at place X and I have a cloned it to my production VM at location 'Y' (same sample.git as BARE only) and have setup a cron task to pull or fetch contents from X to Y @ regular intervals. (cron is working fine)

My concern is that , is it possible to alter the remote(origin) of the Y in such a way that , developers at Y should be able to pull or clone only from the repo @ Y , also Y should maintain its cron task of syncing data from X.

I hope I have put it down clearly !

Comment: Yes, that's one of the basic features of git. Did you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any clone of a git repository is itself a complete git repository. This is what allows for asynchronous work. This is also why any non-bare clone [can be made bare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-normal-git-repository-to-a-bare-one).

In this case, as your clone (`Y`) is also bare, users can clone directly from it. I'm assuming that in your setup users will not be pushing back to `Y`, as this would then cause a conflict when your crontab pulls in changes from `X`. Thus, `Y` should be setup as a read-only repository for users that will be cloning from it, giving write access to the user under whom the crontab will be run.