# Svn externals > git submodules

Tags: git, svn

I am trying to asses the feasibility of converting our jumbo SVN repo to git.
The major issue is that the project has a few hundred externals, some of which are quite beefy.

So far I have created a script that recursively clones all svn externals into their own git repo, and then the main repo defines a whole lot of submodules pointing to my git clones.

The main issue is it seems the externals taking twice the space they should (the clone and the submodule).
Is there a way to have only 1 shared instance of the external clones ?

Comment: I have no idea how the submodule (which is a definition within your project repo) should expand the size of the external cloned repo because the external repo doesn't have a link to your project repo and doesn't even know about beeing a submodule within another repo. Are you sure that there isn't another reason for the size?

Answer (score 1):

> The main issue is it seems the externals taking twice the space they should (the clone and the submodule).

If by twice you mean:

- the submodule repo
- the submodule folder within the main repo, which references the first one

Then it should not be quite twice: the first one (submodule repo) should be a [bare one (or can be made bare)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200662/6309), avoiding to keep two working tree with all their files.

Comment: There is a small problem:
A lot of projects have externals themselves, so from what I can tell, I need a working tree in each submodule (except the repos that have no externals)