# How to convert a git repo to a bare repo

Tags: git

When a repository is cloned by using simple `git clone repo`, the master branch is automatically checked out.  If after this automatic checkout, I want to delete all files checked out and turn the clone in to a bare clone, how can I achieve this?  Are there configurations within the .git folder that I can modify to accomplish this?

Side note: <del>I know that specifying the `--no-checkout` or `-n` flag during clone prevents checkout of `HEAD` and keeps the repository bare.</del>  If I delete the files that are checked out, those files will be shown as deleted when running `git status`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a normal Git repository to a bare one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-normal-git-repository-to-a-bare-one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git clone --no-checkout` doesn't give a bare repository, it just leaves the work tree and index empty. `git status` after such a clone will say that all files have been staged for deletion.

A bare repository is one with `core.bare = true` (and a bare repository made with `git clone --bare` will also not have any remote refs). You can do `git config core.bare true` to flip this bit. Then remove the work tree and index, and possibly rename the directory from `repo/.git` to `repo.git`.

Comment: I did confuse bare and no-checkout.  This is exactly what I was looking for.