# git bare repo: deletions commited after --mirror vs deletions not staged for commit after deleting all except .git

Tags: git, version-control

Ultimately as of now I want a clean way to return to compact (e.g. bare) repo ready to be checked out (Ok, for pedantic ones: after additional `core.bare false`) to any branch. I've read top answers to [How to convert a normal Git repository to a bare one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-normal-git-repository-to-a-bare-one/70254910#70254910). Using `clone` looses config entries as mentioned in comments, below is the problem after trying to use accepted answer. Maybe there is an easy trivial fix to that and that is why I could not find it mentioned in the comments.

*TL;DR*

I'm trying to make sense of info related to bare git repos.

1. To clone all branches:
   [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git/7216269#7216269):

Executed and it worked:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/vmatare/thinkfan.git path/to/dest/.git
cd path/to/dest
git config --bool core.bare false
git checkout master # checkout devel also works with freshly cloned repo
```

`Man git-clone`:

> ```
>    --mirror
>        Set up a mirror of the source repository. This implies --bare.
>        Compared to --bare, --mirror not only maps local branches of the
>        source to local branches of the target, it maps all refs (including
>        remote-tracking branches, notes etc.) and sets up a refspec
>        configuration such that all these refs are overwritten by a git
>        remote update in the target repository.
> ```

Now before `git checkout anybranch` I got `.git` only folder and:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    deleted:    .github/workflows/ccpp.yml
    deleted:    CMakeLists.txt
    deleted:    COPYING
    deleted:    README.md
    ...
```

"deleted" output in green. That is deletions are in index and ready to be committed (as per output and explained in per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458354/git-status-coloring-deleted-files).

2. To convert to bare:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200662/14557599

Executed:

```
cd repo
mv .git ../repo.git # renaming just for clarity
cd ..
rm -fr repo
cd repo.git
git config --bool core.bare true
```

That is deleting all except `.git` and changing `core.bare` config value to `true`.
After that

```
git config --bool core.bare false
```

BTW is

```
git config --bool core.bare true
git config --bool core.bare false
```

Amounts to nothing or some internal status is changed? Anyway, doing both means I followed the upvoted accepted answer to make bare repo. And doing `clone --mirror` I've also made bare repo. But now "deleted" are in red and output is "Changes not staged for commit":

```
git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    deleted:    .github/workflows/ccpp.yml
    deleted:    CMakeLists.txt
    deleted:    COPYING
    deleted:    README.md
    ...
    no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Why is there such a difference between originally cloned repo and then again converted to bare?

I've tried to read comments to the answer to make bare repo but have not noted mentioning that issue.

If now I do `git add *`, then apparently status becomes same as when I just cloned with `--mirror`:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    deleted:    .github/workflows/ccpp.yml
    deleted:    CMakeLists.txt
    deleted:    COPYING
    deleted:    README.md
```

But checkout after than does not work.

```
$ git checkout devel
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    CMakeLists.txt
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

How to see the difference between repo "status" right after `clone --mirror` and after deleting all except `.git` to see why `checkout` works in 1st case but not the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `core.bare` from `true` to `false` is not supported.  Don't expect *anything* to work.

If you know the innards of Git, you can make it work.  (The instructions in the other SO answers were, at least in part, written by those who know how to make it work.)  However, you then know why *not* to combine this with `--mirror`.

Having run `git checkout`, you created an index (aka staging area) in your bare repository.  You'll need to *remove* the index (`rm .git/index`).  That will fix things up, at least temporarily.  But don't go converting bare to non-bare and back like this: it's not supported.

Consider leaving the bare repository bare: you can use `git archive` to get any commit you want from the bare repository.  See [the `git archive` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) for details.  The `git branch` and `git log` commands (and many others) work in a bare repository, allowing you to find hash IDs to supply to `git archive`.

Comment: If "Changing core.bare from true to false is not supported", how to use repo after `clone --mirror` / `clone --bare` w/out it ("fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree" otherwise)? it lets do checkout afterwards, I don't understand what it means in such case  "not supported", I would understand e.g. "undefined behavior".

Comment: `rm .git/index` did help with reverting to only `.git`, still I needed to use `git config --bool core.bare false` after `clone --mirror` which you wrote is not supported, because w/out it  `checkout` failed.

Comment: Don't check out files in a bare repository. That's not what it's for. Use `git clone -n` to avoid the initial checkout in a non-bare repository. (And: "not supported" means: "if you do this, and Git removes all your work or causes your laptop to catch fire, nobody will help you with that." It seems to me that you have some problem you haven't described, have decided that bare clones get you partway there, and are now trying to shoehorn everything into the bare clone process. See also [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).)

Comment: I'm using `clone --mirror` from mentioned Q&A as shortest answer to clone all branches from remote. I thought it is neat as opposed to accepted one telling to do that one by one. And I did not see in comments to ~440 times upvoted `--mirror` answer mentioning dangers of `git config --bool core.bare false` so you answer surprised me.

Comment: P.S. actual is: I want to store sources of software I use in compact form. Occasionally I'd like to see code and then return repo to again compact form. You suggestion of removing index helps to return to compact, but I still need to get repo (all, meaning all branches just in case) in the first place.

Comment: Don't do a mirror clone here. Use a regular clone (perhaps with `-n`) and follow it up with `git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`. That will get you a clone that has the same set of branch names as the original, no current branch yet, and nothing checked out yet, but ready to use.

Comment: To *view* a commit without using `git checkout`, consider using `git archive` to make a tarball or zip file, that you can expand elsewhere (someplace easy to remove).

Comment: " the same set of branch names". banches with full contents / files? at first glance it looks like only pointers, but maybe my guess is wrong.

Comment: Branch names are only pointers (each name stores one hash ID). `git fetch origin "+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*"` means *call up the Git at origin, list out their branch names and hash IDs, make sure we have those commits, and create/update branch names in my repository to match*. Branches don't *hold* commits. Branches *find* commits. Branches don't hold files: commits hold files. Cloning a repository copies commits (usually all of them, but sometimes fewer); without `--mirror`, it copies *no* branch names, but then runs a last `git checkout` that *creates* one branch name.

Comment: If you'd like a bare repository (in which you will never do any work), using `--mirror` is fine, and if you want to inspect commits using `git archive` rather than `git checkout`, a bare clone will work well. So that's probably the way to go here: make a mirror (bare) clone and don't ever check anything out.

Comment: `$ git clone --no-checkout https://github.com/vmatare/thinkfan.git` `cd thinkfan` `git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`: "fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository"

Comment: wanted to reaffirm understanding of your explanation above about commits, but failed at `fetch`

Comment: `git fetch` is the middle step of `git clone`: having made a new, empty repository, `git clone` enters the repository, adds a remote named `origin` to store the URL, then uses `git fetch`. Fetch is the "connect my Git to some other Git repo" operation: we read their branch and other names, find their commits, find which commits *they* have that *we don't*, and get all those commits. Then `git fetch` will create or update names based on the *refspec* (`+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` by default) to remember the commits we got.

Comment: The default refspec creates one *remote-tracking name* in our Git repo, per branch name they have in *their* Git repo. We already got all the commits, now we need some sort of names to find them. Using `--mirror` changes this refspec to `+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`: make a *branch* name in our repo for each *branch* name in their repo. But `--mirror` sets this *permanently* and also causes us to have a `--bare` repo, in which no work should ever be done.

Comment: Note that *any* name, whether it's `refs/heads/somebranch` or `refs/tags/sometag` or `refs/remotes/someremote/theirbranch` or `refs/bisect/*` or `refs/stash` or whatever, contains *exactly one hash ID*. That's all it contains. These are just ways to find Git objects, usually a commit or a tag.

Comment: that is a lot of theory I need to digest to understand how to run `git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` you commented to run. I edited the question to add IMO important detail from comments to feel good about accepting the answer w/out understanding all that theory beforehand.

Comment: @Martian2020: Yes, I think your edit was a good idea. I tweaked it a bit and put it in.

Comment: yes, thank you. `man` was Linux specific, which was not mentioned in the question.