# How to add existing repository to gitea from filesystem?

Tags: gitea

I have some bare git repository on my filesystem where users do pull/push.
I install gitea and can't find how to add it to gitea.
Other git-management systems have something like "add repository from filesystem", "scan directory", etc. which added existing repo to system.
How to add it in gitea?

Answer (score 6):

At the moment I migrate from Filesystem Repositorys to Gitea.

How this could be done is heavily discussed [here](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/1635) (we used SSH), where I got the basis for my approach.

The following steps worked for me:

1. Clone the repo.git folder to another location `git clone path/to/repo.git`
2. Create an empty repo in Gitea. Either by hand or using the api

   ```
   curl \
     -X POST "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/repos" \
     -H "accept: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: token MY_TOKEN*" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d "{\"name\": \"REPO_NAME\"}" \
     -i
   ```
3. Optionally transfer to a organization

   ```
   curl \
     -X POST "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/repos/CURRENT_OWNER/REPO_NAME/transfer" \
     -H "accept: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: token MY_TOKEN*" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d "{\"new_owner\": \"NEW_ORGANIZATION_OR_INDIVIDUAL\"}" \
     -i
   ```
4. Push the repo to gitea

- `git remote add neworigin "http://localhost:3000/username/test.git"`
- `git push neworigin --all`
- `git push neworigin --tags`

*https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/api-usage/

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I think it will be more complete if a step to transfer to an organization is added.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. You're a savior. I wrote a C# app, which reads the repository table from the old Gitea MsSql DB, and then using the gitea API creates the repositories in the new Gitea (with a MySql DB), transfers ownership to an organization, and then executes git commands to clone old repositories, add the new-origin and push to the new Gitea. Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'unadopted repositories' method (merged  in [this pull request](https://gitea.com/lunny/gitea/pulls/12920) as of sep 2020).

1. Locate gitea's `app.ini` config file and find the values of `APP_NAME` (the user name) and the repositories `ROOT`. 
   Let's assume your config looks like this:

```ini
APP_NAME = dinsdale
...
[repository]
ROOT = /usr/local/data/gitea-repositories
```

2. `cd` to `$REPO/$APP_NAME` which for the config above will be: `/usr/local/data/gitea-repositories/dinsdale` and make a bare clone from each repo on your local file system:

```bash
cd /usr/local/data/gitea-repositories/dinsdale

git clone --bare /path/to/my/local/repo1
git clone --bare /path/to/my/local/repo2
..
git clone --bare /path/to/my/local/repo42
```

3. Click your profile icon in the top right corner and select <kbd>**Site Administration**</kbd> -> tab <kbd>**Repositories**</kbd> -> click <kbd>**Unadopted Repositories**</kbd>.
4. Leave the search field blank, and click the **Search** button. The 'unadopted' orphan folders that you added will be displayed below.
5. For each repo click the <kbd>Adopt Files</kbd> button to import the orphaned repo.

<sub>To manually convert a regular repo to a bare one see [*How to convert a normal Git repository to a bare one?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200662/191246)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There is also a built-in feature called push to create that allows you to create new repos on the fly from existing repos. You need to add both there options inside the repository block in app.ini as shown below then just restart the gitea daemon.

```
[repository]
ENABLE_PUSH_CREATE_USER = true
ENABLE_PUSH_CREATE_ORG =  true
```

After this is done you can run the following commands to push and create the repo on demand.

```
git remote add origin git@{domain}:{username}/{repo name that does not exist yet}.git
git push -u origin main
```

See more at https://docs.gitea.com/usage/push#enabling-push-to-create