# GIT - Force Override of remote repository

Tags: git

My server provider somehow deleted the remote repository and so i need to override it with my local copy. 
However when i do git push origin master it says everything is up to date - but it's definitely not.

How can i force GIT to push all files regardless of the remote state?

Comment: When you say 'deleted the remote repository' what exactly do you mean?

Comment: what exactly is deleted for you? removed history? physically removed the directory from the server? `everything up-to-date` usually hints at a complete history on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this [When creating a git repository that will be on the server, can I convert it to a bare repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784506/when-creating-a-git-repository-that-will-be-on-the-server-can-i-convert-it-to-a)

Then copy the bare version to the server.

Comment: Then clone that empty repo, copy over all of the files, commit and push this *initial commit*. You'll lose all the history, but you'll look smart, like doing it all in one piece :D